# React typeerror: Cannot read property of undefined - But I can read other props just fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-redux

I am puzzled by this undefined error.  Here is my object that I can console.log from render()

```
{_id: "59e7ac89d14e6d644588eaff", title: "500 thread count sateen sheet set", id: "1233", description: "Sink into dreamland with a luxe sheet set in smoot…at and fitted sheets, along with two pillowcases.", type: "Duvet", …}
addedDate
:
"2017-10-18T19:33:29.468Z"
collectiontype
:
"String"
description
:
"Sink into dreamland with a luxe sheet set in smooth, lustrous organic-cotton sateen that includes flat and fitted sheets, along with two pillowcases."
holiday
:
""
id
:
"1233"
image1
:
{_id: "59e7ac89d14e6d644588eafd"}
image2
:
{_id: "59e7ac89d14e6d644588eafe"}
options
:
{color: Array(2), size: Array(5)}
price
:
(4) [89, 99, 119, 129]
season
:
"All"
subtype
:
""
tags
:
[""]
title
:
"500 thread count sateen sheet set"
type
:
"Duvet"
__v
:
0
_id
:
"59e7ac89d14e6d644588eaff"
__proto__
:
Object
```

On the first render the object is, in fact, undefined.  I handle this by assigning each property to an empty type.  Eg:

```
const price = this.props.detail.price || []
```

For some reason, regardless of what I do, I cannot access the props of the options obj: color and size.  Even this causes the typeError:

```
const color = this.props.detail.options.color || []
```

I have no issue accessing and rendering all other props except options.color and options.size.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of a constant?

Comment: Lodash is awesome: `const color = _.get(this.props.detail.options, 'color') || [];`

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks, Chase.  Palsrealm's solution works as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your options object is undefined when you do

```
const color = this.props.detail.options.color || []
```

Try doing

```
const color= this.props.detail.options? this.props.detail.options.color || [] :[];
```

Comment: Thanks, @palsrealm. This fixed the issue! Chase's lodash solution also works.

Comment: I'm a fan of this more concise way:
const color = (this.props.detail.options || {}).color || [];